# Radio button not working in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a form where i will be having 2 radio buttons. one for 'public' and onother for 'private'.

I have a User model in my project and i have privacy field in it which is boolean and its default value is true(that is 'public' in my case).

I have update button in my form. I want to submit the form and accordingly want to update the value in User model. and then if whenever i visit edit page the corresponding radio button should be selected.

This is my form

```
= form_tag "/users/abc" do
    %p.heading We Respect Your Privacy
    .privacy
      %input#r1{:name => "privacy", :type => "radio", :value => 0}
        %label.privacyLabel{:for => "r1"}
          %span>
          Friends Only
        %p
          TraveLibro enables you to save your travel memories and share them with your friends. While other TraveLibro users
          can see your itineraries, only your friends on TraveLibro can view your personal pictures.
        %br
          %p Now you can upload all your captured memories without ever having to be concerned about your privacy.
    .privacy
      %input#r2{:name => "privacy", :type => "radio", :value => 1}
        %label.privacyLabel{:for => "r2"}
          %span>
          Everyone
        %p
          Want to share your travel tales with the world. With an open profile TraveLibro users can view the itineraries
          you have created and the pictures that complete those memories.
    .privacyUpdate
      %a{:href => "javascript:void(0);"}
        %input.privacyUpdateBtn{:type => "submit", :value => "update"}/
```

and this is my controller action

```
def abc
  current_user.update_column('privacy', params[:privacy] == 0 ? 0 : 1)
  redirect_to :back
end
```

But its not working

Comment: Check `params[:privacy] == '0'  ? 0 : 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def abc
  current_user.update_column('privacy', params[:privacy].to_i == 0 ? 0 : 1)
  redirect_to :back
end
```